# ListView with Image Loader not loading efficienty

Tags: android, image, listview

My ListView is not scrolling smoothly. It's like it always reloads the image from API. I want to have it scrolling smoothly.

The library that I am using to load the images is **Universal Image Loader**.

**JAVA**

```
String url = MainActivity.IMAGE_URL + "postid=" + model.get(position).getId();
loader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code after trying Universal ImageLoader, Picasso and Glide library, And it is fastest for me using RecyclerView.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(URL_OF_IMAGE)
.error(R.drawable.blank)
.config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.resizeDimen(R.dimen.d50dp, R.dimen.d50dp)
.centerCrop()
.into(holder.imageview);
```

Check this owesome link that shows difference with respect to load time and memory in detail,
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) will use very less memory and .resizeDimen(R.dimen.d50dp, R.dimen.d50dp) will load small image from memory so will take very less time and memory.

Comment: I have changed to Picasso, but how can I still fix this error when I scroll down then up the image reloads again. Like in the video, that I've recorded. https://youtu.be/sV57QFAc7FU (new video)

Comment: Nevermind it's fixed. After I've changed to Picasso my App didn't notice that. I've cleared my app in task and cleared, rebuild the project. Now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your `DisplayImageOptions` with extra caching capabilities.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.avatar)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.avatar)
        .cacheInMemory(true) // default is false
        .cacheOnDisk(true) // default is false
        .build();
```

Source: [DisplayImageOptions](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Display-Options)

You can also change default `ImageLoaderConfiguration` and change cache size or increase thread priority (if you like). Note that you only need to set this configuration once in you application unlike DisplayImageOptions. See: [ImageLoaderConfiguration](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Configuration)